# Is either Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics or Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus good as analysis text?

Tags: analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation

Is either G. Hardy's A Course of Pure Mathematics or Richard Courant's Differential and Integral Calculus good as analysis text? Are they sufficiently rigorous for what we would call a analysis (in the sense of rigor) nowadays? Or it is definitely better to get a analysis text taking into account the distinction made between calculus and analysis nowadays?